# Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "v2_0_0_full.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, cert-manager

I am trying to follow the instruction of AWS to create an ALB for EKS (Elastic K8s Services in AWS).
The instruction is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html
I have problems at step 7 (Install the controller manually). When I try to apply a yaml file in substep 7-b-c, I get an error:

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "v2_0_0_full.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s: x509: certificate is valid for ip-192-168-121-78.eu-central-1.compute.internal, not cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc
```

Has anyone experienced similar kind of problem and what are the best ways to troubleshoot and solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/) doesn't run on Fargate as expected - [#1606](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/1606).

First option as a workaround is to install the helm chart which doesn't have the cert-manager dependency. Helm will generate the self-signed cert, and secret resources.

Different option is to remove all cert-manager stuff from the YAML manifest and provide your own self-signed certificate if you  don't have helm as a dependency.

Take a look: [alb-cert-manager](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/1563/726859452), [alb-eks-cert-manager](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/1563).

Useful article: [aws-fargate](https://medium.com/@yspreen/get-started-with-fargate-on-aws-https-ingress-991a09020cc0).

Answer (score 1):

For EKS with Fargate, cert-manager-webhook server's port clashes with kubelet on the Fargate MicroVM.

Ref: https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/3237#issuecomment-827523656

To remedy this, when installing the chart set the parameter webhook.securePort to a port that is not 10250 (e.g. 10260)

helm install 
cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager 
--namespace cert-manager 
--create-namespace 
--version v1.3.1 
--set webhook.securePort=10260
--set installCRDs=true

Or you could edit the cert-manager-webhook Deployment and Service to use this new port if cert-manager is already deployed.